# Receiving an error when trying to run 'scrapy crawl'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

After I run 'scrapy crawl word' I receive an error. I am trying to use Scrapy to scrape the fda website. I am following the tutorial online. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class WordSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "word"

def start_requests(self):
    start_url = [
        'https://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/'
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url
    filename = 'www.fda-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

I've changed the code a little because I only need one url and the 'www' is important for the link to work.

The error I am getting is:

```
:0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'No module named cryptography.x509'.
```

I tried doing installing service_identity but I received the same error. Not sure if my code is incorrect or I am missing some package.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing some packages for TLS, I would suggest to install cryptography and OpenSSL packages.

```
pip install cryptography
```

OpenSSL:

- Mac --> `brew install openssl`
- Windows --> http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/fpc/OpenSSLforWin64.en.aspx
- Linux --> https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation